# Sending only the updated object from ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

How can I send only the updated model from an observable Array instead of sending the entire array?

```
var student = function (){
    this.studentId=0;
    this.firstName=ko.obserable();
    this.lastName=ko.obserable();
}
var course= function (){
    this.courseId=0;
    this.students=ko.obserableArray([]);
    this.Name=ko.obserable();
}
```

Now I want to get only that particular student from course whose info is updated. Assuming that when we add a new class we can dynamically add new students to it on the go. Supposing that you have to validate the previous student before adding a new one. When I get that particular student I want to send that student info back to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by validating the previous student before adding a new one?

Comment: I have an (add more) button which adds new student into the DOM and in the DB. Validating means that if the user has entered valid info of student then he can add another student into that class.

Comment: I post the answer on how to get list of students which have been modified.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your task right, you could use "arrayChange" event type to get exact changed (added/removed) items:

```
sourceArray = ko.observableArray();
sourceArray.subscribe(function (changes) {
        changes.forEach(function(arrayChange) {
            if(arrayChange.status === 'added') {
                // some code on add
            } else if(arrayChange.status === 'deleted') {
                // some code on delete
            }
        });
    }, null, "arrayChange");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of students which have been modified, you can provide a flag to identify if an object has been modified in student object. Use `.subscribe` to modify that flag whenever a value is updated. Then use `ko.computed` or `ko.pureComputed` to get that list.

Also it supposes to be `observable`.

```js
var student = function (id, firstName, lastName) {
  var self = this;
  self.hasChanged = ko.observable(false);
  var modified = function(){
    self.hasChanged(true);
  };

  self.studentId = ko.observable(id);
  self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  self.firstName.subscribe(modified);
  self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
  self.lastName.subscribe(modified);
}
var course= function (){
  var self = this;
  self.courseId = 0;
  self.students = ko.observableArray([new student(1, "Cristiano", "Ronaldo"), new student(2, "Lionel", "Messi")]);
  self.modifiedStudent = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.students(), function(student) {
        return student.hasChanged();
    });
  }, self);
  self.Name = ko.observable("Programming 101");
}  

$(document).ready(function () {
  var myViewModel = new course();
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

List of all students:
<div data-bind="foreach: students">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: studentId"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/>

List of students which has been modified:
<div data-bind="foreach: modifiedStudent">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: studentId"></span>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" readonly />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```